# What is correct way to write d.ts file for js function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I know there are a lot of questions related to this problem. I searched again and read all questions twice. I get some results but not all I want. Please help me to find my mistake.

These are my js and d.ts files

```
//other.js file
function myFunction() {
console.log("Hello from d.ts file");
}
```

And

```
//other.d.ts file
export module other {
  function myFunction(): void;
}
```

I use from my component like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log((other as any).myFunction());
}
```

My import statements are below:

```
import * as other from '../js/other'
```

Everything compiles fine and builds succesfully but when I check at localhost it gives the error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__js_other**.myFunction is not a function
>   TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__js_other**.myFunction is not a function
>       at MineComponent.webpackJsonp.156.MineComponent.ngOnInit (mine.component.ts:39)

My directory is like this:

[image]

Comment: Can't you write typescript version for your js so that when you are converting it into .d.ts you get better and accurate type definition.

Comment: The problem is that your js file doesn't have anything named as other, and the browser understands only js not ts file and that is why it throws an error there , not in your IDE.

Comment: @GauravPandvia no I must use only js files.Because I have no time to write ts version for all js files :/ Do you know how can i fix it in js file?

Comment: Did you try to add export keyword?

Comment: in other.js ?yes,it gives "Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined" :(

Answer (score 0):

Your other.js file should be encapsulated in a class and should be made available in the exports to be used.

```
    //other.js file
var other = (function(){

  function other(){
    //init class properties...
  }
  other.prototype.myFunction = function() {
     console.log("Hello from d.ts file");
  } 
    /**
    * add to global namespace
    */


} )();
exports.other = other;
```

Then in your component ts file you can use it by writing on top of the file at imports level directly:-

```
declare var other:any
```

Or if you have mentioned your .d.ts files correctly like the class and its protype properties as its internal functions:-

```
//other.d.ts
export declare class other{
  myFunction(): void;
}
```

Comment: now I can find declaration myFunction from js file to d.ts file.But in component I can not acces,it cannot find declaration

Comment: Try this `declare var other:any` in your component

Comment: it didn't help.But anyway thank your for your reply.